Reshaping data from long to wide format using data within a column in R
I am attempting to change the format of my dataset from long to wide format in order to create a matrix. The data is currently structured as:



year
data.type
plot
species
presence




2024
nc
35
Acer rubrum
1


2024
nc
35
Carya glabra
1


2024
nc
36
Acer rubrum
1


2024
nc
118
Carya aquatica
1


2024
nc
39
Acer rubrum
1


2024
nc
116
Carya glabra
1


2024
nc
33
Acer rubrum
1


2024
nc
112
Carya glabra
1



This is however a simplified version as there are hundreds of unique species in this dataset, but often the same species are recorded many times in different plots.
I would like to restructure the data so that each unique species is a different column and the data attributed is presence/absence data such as:



year
data.type
plot
Acer rubrum
Carya aquatica
Carya glabra




2024
nc
35
1
0
1


2024
nc
118
0
1
0



I assume that I will need to create a loop code for this, but I'm not sure exactly where to start and whether melt, reshape, or another similar function would be best for this sort of thing. Thanks in advance!
I have tried some basic code with melt, but of course am expecting that I need more sophisticated code for this dataset.
